# Django ORM – Check if a field is Null in database

Tags: django-models

I want to filter the objects based on their field being NULL in the database. I am using Django 1.7.1 and I want to use the following

```
frames = Frame.objects.filter(asset_id=None)
print frames
```

I get one frame whose asset_id field is NULL but for other frames I get the following error.

```
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Frame.objects.filter(asset_id__isnull=True)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#isnull

Comment: It is the problem of print, the query is working fine. I need to edit my post.

Comment: You're probably outputting `frame.asset` in `unicode` method then. Also, you should really use `isnull` lookup instead to comparing to None.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzularz Why use isnull instead of None?

Comment: Using `isnull` generates correct SQL query as opposed to using `=None`.